# Can we initialize an object/collection using LINQ in JSON-like syntax?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, json, c#-3.0

**Can we do something like this or something similar?**

```
var staffs = {
               "Staff": 
               [
                { "ID" : 1, "Name" : "John" },
                { "ID" : 2, "Name" : "Mark"}
               ]
            };

foreach (var staff in staffs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", staff.ID);
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", staff.Name);
}
```

**Instead of this long code:**

```
public class Test
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
            return;

        List<Staff> staffs = new List<Staff>()
        {
            new Staff() {ID = 1, Name = "John"},
            new Staff() {ID = 2, Name = "Mark"}
        };

        foreach (var staff in staffs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", staff.ID);
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", staff.Name);
        }
    }
}

public class Staff
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I tried but Visual Studio shows syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it shorter but not exactly like JSON.

```
List<Staff> staffs = new List<Staff>()
{
    new Staff() {ID = 1, Name = "John"},
    new Staff() {ID = 2, Name = "Mark"}
};
```

...can you turn into: (This is an array not a `List<T>` but you can wrap it)

```
var staffs = new[]
{
    new Staff {ID = 1, Name = "John"},
    new Staff {ID = 2, Name = "Mark"}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope. What you've demonstrated is the allowed syntax for collection and object initializers.

If you're trying to shorten it somewhat you could drop the trailing `()` off of each initializer, such as:

```
var list = new List<Staff>
{
    new Staff {ID = 1, Name = "John"},
    new Staff {ID = 2, Name = "Mark"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is:

```
var staffs = new List<Staff> {
                new Staff{ ID : 1, Name : "John" },
                new Staff{ ID : 2, Name : "Mark"}

            };

foreach (var staff in staffs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", staff.ID);
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", staff.Name);
}
```

Note: member names and values are not quoted, but strongly typed (unlike json).

You might be able to *deserialize* a JSON representation directly to the object graph using a Json serializer.